# String was not recognized as a valid boolean in C# RadioButton

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to send values from one form to another form, which means when i click on a button then i want to send student values to another form through id column. However, I have got an error regarding string was not recognized when i want to send RadioButton values.

Please note, I do not save RadioButton values as string i.e. Male or Female into the database.

Here is the code itself.

```
if (this.isupdate)
{
    DataTable dtStudentInfo =  GetAllStudentInfoById(this.StudentId);
    DataRow row = dtStudentInfo.Rows[0];
    tbID.Text = row["std_id"].ToString();
    tbName.Text = row["std_name"].ToString();
    tbFatherName.Text = row["std_f_name"].ToString();
    tbAddress.Text = row["std_address"].ToString();
    tbBatchNo.Text = row["std_batch"].ToString();
    tbBatchYear.Text = row["std_batch_year"].ToString();
    tbCNIC.Text = row["std_cnic"].ToString();
    tbMobNumber.Text = row["std_mob"].ToString();
    rbMale.Checked = (row["std_gender"] is DBNull) ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(row["std_gender"] = 1) ? true : false);

}
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `std_gender` column?

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean(row["std_gender"] == 1)`

Comment: @rory.ap the data type Varchar(50)

Answer (score 7):

A small typo makes a who lot of a difference.

```
Convert.ToBoolean(row["std_gender"] = 1)
```

Was meant to be (the convert is unnecessary here):

```
Convert.ToBoolean(row["std_gender"] == 1)
```

The typo caused the `row["std_gender"]` to be set to 1, which makes the convert fail.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `== "1"` since it's a string?

Comment: Who says it is a string?

Comment: I think that is an issue related to the inner working of setting the value.

Comment: why do you still need to call Convert.ToBoolean when == 1 already returns a bool

Comment: You don't. That is what I said, right? @Steve. That code is just to show the coding mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Convert.ToBoolean(row["std_gender"].ToString() == "1")
```

Comment: A little late to the party, eh?

Comment: ohhh sheet, better luck next time to me ;)

Comment: @rory kh aafi should try and reply :P

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt already tried... Hence the error removed but don't  load the gender to radiobuttons

Comment: `               rbMale.Checked = (row["std_gender"] is DBNull) ? false : (Convert.ToInt32(row["std_gender"]) == 1) ? true : false;
`

Comment: this query is also not working... got an error of input string was not in a correct format @AnkitkumarBhatt

Comment: can you please check the value of row["std_gender"] in watch window and let me know?

Answer (score -1):

Solved..!!!
Code was right... Just a lil error with the returning type....

```
private object GetGender()
    {
        if (rbMale.Checked)
        {
            return (int)Gender.Male;
        }
        else if (rbFemale.Checked)
        {
            return (int)Gender.Female;
        }
        else
        {
            return (int)Gender.NoSelection;
        }
    }
```

Just changed the return type from object to int and also change the data type of gender from varchar to int...Here is the code

```
private int GetGender()
    {
        if (rbMale.Checked)
        {
            return (int)Gender.Male;
        }
        else if (rbFemale.Checked)
        {
            return (int)Gender.Female;
        }
        else
        {
            return (int)Gender.NoSelection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @rory.ap Maybe or may be not but its solved ma problem... Anyhow i think i didn't explain my problem with you people... sorry for that...